# How to know process interrupted in python?

Tags: python, mysql, try-catch

from my debug log , I found my process have been interrupted , I  have set try-catch in my code as below,

```
         try:
            print "update query : ........"
            query = ("Update Logs set id  = "+str(id)+" where Sid = '"+str(id)+"'")
            cursor.execute(query)
            conn.commit()
         except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
            sqlerrlogs = open("/log/mysqlerr.log","a")
            sqlerrlogs.write(str(datetime.now()))
            sqlerrlogs.write('\n')
            sqlerrlogs.write(e)
            sqlerrlogs.write('\n\n')
```

but from my log , after print "update query : ........" , there's no error in my log ,how to fix my code in order to know what's happened ?
my python version is 2.7

Comment: How do you run your process?

Comment: run cron every two minutes

Comment: You really don't want to use string interpolation on your data, you are wide open to SQL injection attacks there. Use query parameters (instead of `"  + str(value) + "` use a placeholder `%s` and pass in a sequence of values as the second argument to `cursor.execute()`).

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the `where Sid = ?` query simply didn't match any rows? How do you know that anything was interrupted at all?

Comment: Sid value is exist, because from the debug log , before execute the update query  I have have  print "update query : Update Logs set id  = "+str(id)+" where Sid = '"+str(id)+"'"

Answer (score 0):

You could catch all errors, not just the MySQLdb-related errors:

```
import traceback
try:
    print "update query : ........"
    query = ("Update Logs set id  = "+str(id)+" where Sid = '"+str(id)+"'")
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
except:
    err = traceback.format_exc()
    sqlerrlogs = open("/log/mysqlerr.log","a")
    sqlerrlogs.write(str(datetime.now()))
    sqlerrlogs.write('\n')
    sqlerrlogs.write(err)
    sqlerrlogs.write('\n\n')
```